# Find the cycle index of cyclic group $C_p$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Find the [cycle index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) of cyclic group $C_p$ where $p$ is prime.

No idea where to start...any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How is cycle index defined? Also, could you make the question self-contained, such that the question itself does not only appear in the title?

Comment: The answer is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Cyclic_group_Cn).